# ASP.MVC MVC: how not to repeat a loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

As it can be clearly seen in this code, I need 3(!!!) loops to populate certain elements of the page. What's the best way to avoid it? Is it acceptable in ASP.NET MVC framework to do such a thing? It doesn't seem right.

```
<div id="center_box">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="head">

            <h3></h3> -- <!--LOOP 1 to insert title-->
        </div>
        <ul id="center_items_rb">
               <!--LOOP 2 to insert #of <LI> according to benefits count-->
            <li class="checked" onclick="javascript:SelectCenterItem(this, 1);"></li>
            <li class="not_checked" onclick="javascript:SelectCenterItem(this, 2);"></li>
            <li class="not_checked" onclick="javascript:SelectCenterItem(this, 3);"></li>
            <li class="not_checked" onclick="javascript:SelectCenterItem(this, 4);"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <!--Loop 3-->
        @foreach (var topBenefit in Model.TopBenefits)
        {
            <div id="center_item_@(topBenefit.BenefitID)">
                @Html.Image("content/Images/@(topBenefit.BenefitImage)", "")
                <div class="line">
                    <div class="right">
                        <h2>
                            @string.IsNullOrEmpty(topBenefit.Description)
                            ? @topBenefit.Description.Substring(0, 100) + "..." 
                            : @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NoDescriptionBenefit"]
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>         
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, its not clear what you are trying to do. If you are concerned about looping over `Model.TopBenefits` multiple times, I don't see why.

Comment: Not familiar with this templating language, but I only see one loop in your snippet: `@foreach`. *edit:* Thanks for the edit, still don't see how printing the HTML header can be considered a loop though. :-) Regardless, I wouldn't worry about sequentially executed loops.

Comment: sorry, I jsut added the palces where multiple loops are needed

Comment: @GuyZ: Are you saying you want multiple `<h3>`'s with titles on a page, each of them followed by a `div class="pic">` containing pictures? Then you should add the actual looping code for that too to make your question more clear.

Comment: i've read this question 3 times and it's just not clear what you are trying to achieve.. judging by the other comments and answers, no-one else gets it either.. Not a good post.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best way to avoid it?

By using a display template:

```
<div id="center_box">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="head">
            <h3></h3> --
        </div>
        <ul id="center_items_rb">
            <li class="checked" onclick="javascript:SelectCenterItem(this, 1);"></li>
            <li class="not_checked" onclick="javascript:SelectCenterItem(this, 2);"></li>
            <li class="not_checked" onclick="javascript:SelectCenterItem(this, 3);"></li>
            <li class="not_checked" onclick="javascript:SelectCenterItem(this, 4);"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TopBenefits)
    </div>
</div>
```

and inside the corresponding display template which will be rendered automatically for each element of the `TopBenefits` collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/TopBenefit.cshtml`)

```
@model TopBenefit
<div id="center_item_@(Model.BenefitID)">
    @Html.Image("content/Images/@(Model.BenefitImage)", "")
    <div class="line">
        <div class="right">
            <h2>
                @string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Description)
                ? @Model.Description.Substring(0, 100) + "..." 
                : @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NoDescriptionBenefit"]
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the name and location of the display template is important. It should be located in the `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` if it is meant to be reused between multiple controllers and inside `~/Views/SomeController/DisplayTemplates` if it is really specific to a given controller and it should be named as the type of the elements of the collection property.

Comment: That dosent answer the question since the 2 other loops are outside this one

Comment: @GuyZ, where are they? Why haven't you shown them in your question? What do they contain? What are they looping over? What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

is `Model.TopBenefits` of type `IEnumberable`? If so:

```
@foreach (var topBenefit in Model.TopBenefits.Take(3))
```

will iterate over the first 3 benefits

Comment: It's not that...the loop is taking all the benefits and populates different elements on the page...not just the top 3